# Recompile Dependencies in Maven 2

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

In the pom for a webapp, I'm looking for a way to recompile the local source code for two dependencies, then copy those jars over to the webapp's WEB-INF/lib directory. Is there a Maven 2 plugin that would allow me to do this, or some better approach using Maven 2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an easy way to do that.

One solution is to put all three projects in a reactor (a project with ), they will build in the right order when the reactor project is invoked.

Comment: Well, the reason I'm looking for the thing described above is for when I edit the source code after the webapp is deployed in Tomcat, so I can implement the changes without re-deploying.

Comment: If you're using eclipse and have all projects open in your workspace, m2e will convert the maven dependencies into workspace resolution dependencies (i.e. not copy stuff into WEB-INF/lib, but add target/classes directly to the classpath), and should allow you to do that without pom change. I don't know about other IDEs, but I'd expect something similar.